# App parent string variable is going back to being empty after being set by service call

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have two app components with a parent/child relationship. AppComponent is the parent while ConfigComponent is the child. When I startup my app, AppComponent makes a service call inside its constructor to set a variable e.g.

```
// I've simplified my code to illustrate my issue. I've done all the proper 
// service imports, providers, etc. 

// AppComponent (the parent)
public configName: string = "";

constructor(//params here) {
    console.log("App constructor called.");

    this.getConfigName();

    // Since I've already called the service method to obtain the config name, 
    // I expect the following line to print out the config name that was retrievevd, but instead it prints out nothing i.e. an empty string
    console.log("Config name is: " + this.configName);
}

getConfigName() {
    this.configService.getGATRConfigName()
        .subscribe(res => this.configName = res;
        console.log("Config name is: " + this.configName); // This prints out the proper name
    );
}

// ConfigComponent (the child)
public configName: string = "";

constructor(private appParent: AppComponent) {
    this.configName = this.appParent.configName; 
    // After this line is executed, this.configName is still an 
    // empty string - if I can figure out why the parent component 
    // doesn't seem to set the variable properly then I imagine 
    // this would work the way I want it to. 
}
```

I've also noticed that if I manually set configName in the AppComponent parent, e.g.:

```
this.configName = "Config Name Default";
```

then it stays and I can pull that variable from the child component and get "Config Name Default" back. For some reason `this.configName` goes back to being an empty string and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend using input relation between parent and client components. Read more here: https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/

Answer (score 1):

Your config value isn't going back to empty, getGATRConfigName hasn't actually triggered the event that the subscribe is listening for.  You'll need to setup some sort of promise that you resolve in your subscribe that then other things can refer to in order to know when you've actually finished loading.